# Android Studio code style scheme auto reset to the default every start

Tags: android, android-studio

After I update Android Studio to 3.2.x, every time I create a project, its Code Style Scheme (in Preference -> Editor -> Code Style) auto be default "Project", not what I set scheme stored in IDE before.

After I set the project code style scheme format to scheme which stored in IDE and "apply", every time I start Android Studio to open this project, then its code style scheme auto be default "Project" again!

What is the problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 45):

After a lot of work, I solved this problem as below:

Open `gradle.properties` file in project root directory, I find code `kotlin.code.style=official`, simply delete this line code, then the problem is solved.

Maybe Android Studio is confused by this code, or code style set by this line code have conflict with the Code Style Scheme set in IDE. If what i guess is right, then this is a bug of Android Studio.

Comment: Did this, recopied the settings from IDE to Project and so far it seems to be holding!

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and it was confusing, Some times by mistake it put a huge change in commits because I always use 2 spaces but default code style uses 4. Removing that line solved it